# timer to check the end of the file bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using a code basically runs to restart a calculation after one finishes. The code was working fine. But i wanna improvise the code. Right now it runs on a timer function sleep. It never checks for the end of the file. So it waits 22 min to submit the next job irrespective of the previous job. So i want to change the code in such a way it checks the end of the file every one minute for the keyword "End of program" from the log file and submits the next job. Please drop me a msg if you have any ideas ...

---

while ( 1 )

---

#sleep for X seconds/minutes

```
    $SLEEP 22m
    #cut JobID into peeces:
    #e.g.: 31380.chic1i20.informatik.tu-chemnitz.de Info: Your job definition is checked against CHiC policies. --> 31380.chic1i20
    #set JOBnr = `echo $JOBID | $CUT -c-15`
    set JOBnr = `echo $JOBID | $CUT -d " " -f1 | $CUT -d "." -f-2`
    $QSTAT -nu "$USER" > .qstat_outfile
    if ( "$?" ) then
            echo "autorestart: qstat error"
            $CAT .qstat_outfile
            continue
    endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UNWRITTEN=0
while [ $UNWRITTEN -eq 0 ]; do
 token=$(tail -n 2 .qstat_outfile)
 echo $token
 if [[ $token == "End of program" ]]
 then
     echo "autorestart..."
     UNWRITTEN=1
 fi
 sleep 60
done
```

Explanation:

- Program continually loops until it find the correct line at the end of the logfile. Then it restarts your calculations and exits.
- `tail -n 2` reads the last two lines (which is actually the *last* line if there is a newline after  "End of program". You may need to adjust this to -n 1 on your system.)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, a while-loop like this may help you:

```
stop=0
while [ $stop == 0 ]; do 
    tail -1 $LOGFILE | grep -q "End of program" && stop=1 || sleep 60 
done
```

(It checks the last line (`tail -1`) of LOGFILE for the presence of your search text, stops
 if text is found or sleeps for 60 seconds if not).